# ElasticBeanstalk - Changing java.security?

Tags: java, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to change the `securerandom.source` value in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` on my Elastic Beanstalk instance.

How can I do that through the .ebextensions? Or is the another way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` file, there's a paragraph saying

```
# This is the "master security properties file".
#
# An alternate java.security properties file may be specified
# from the command line via the system property
#
#    -Djava.security.properties=<URL>
#
# This properties file appends to the master security properties file.
# If both properties files specify values for the same key, the value
# from the command-line properties file is selected, as it is the last
# one loaded.
```

So you may create a `java-security.config` file with the following content under `.ebextensions` folder:

```
# Create a file named java-security under /usr/share/tomcat8/conf to override the default value of securerandom.source
files: 
  "/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/java-security" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: tomcat
    group: tomcat
    content: |
      securerandom.source=<the file you want for securerandom.source>
```

Then go to elastic beanstalk environment

-> Configuration

-> Software

-> Environment properties

-> type `java.security.properties` for *Name*, and `/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/java-security` for *Value*.

Then restart the tomcat. Your `securerandom.source` should be changed to the value you wish.

One thing to remember is that the user `tomcat` must have permissions to read `/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/java-security` file.